# Can't update table 'example_table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write a very simple query. I couldn't solve this problem.

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `example_trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `example_table`
FOR EACH ROW
if (new.result = 1) THEN
update  example_table set result = 2 where result=0 and costumer_id = new.costumer_id;
end if;
```

When I update the result as 1, I would like to update the result of the other records that belong to that customer to 2.
But I get this error:

```
Can't update table 'example_table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I tried to write the procedure, but it didn't work again.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit:

Example table:

```
id   customer_id    result
1         12           0
2         12           5
3         14           4
4         12           3
5         12           0
6         12           0
7         16           3
```

Query:

```
UPDATE example_table SET result=1 WHERE customer_id=12 AND id=4
```

Then the trigger will work.

And I need:

```
   id   customer_id    result
    1         12           2      ->trigger
    2         12           5
    3         14           4
    4         12           1      ->update
    5         12           2      ->trigger
    6         12           2      ->trigger
    7         16           3
```

Comment: Can you share the code which executes the UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run `show triggers;` from the cli or from [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to see if you have a trigger named `example_trigger` or if there are *any* triggers set for `AFTER UPDATE ON example_table`.

You can only have 1 trigger named `example_trigger` and only 1 trigger for `AFTER UPDATE ON example_table`.

Then, changing your code to the following should fix your problem:

```
DROP TRIGGER example_trigger;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `example_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `example_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF (NEW.result = 1) THEN
    SET NEW.result = 2;
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

In your code, you give the `IF result=1` condition, then give the `WHERE result=0` in the update statement.  This will result in your trigger never updating anything (or giving errors).  Also, you can simplify your code a lot by using the `BEFORE UPDATE` like in my example, since you can simply `SET NEW.col = x` instead of having to run an entire `UPDATE` statement.

Also, you misspelled "customer" :)

### Update

You can use a `CASE` statement to achieve this with a single `UPDATE` query.  Note that you will have to disable "safe updates" to do this.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

UPDATE example_table 
SET result = CASE
    WHEN id=4 THEN 1
    WHEN result=0 THEN 2
    ELSE result
    END WHERE customer_id = 12;
```

Comment: Sorry my english is so bad. I want to change the results of that other customer record. For example: I updated result=1. I would like to update the result of other records of this customer to 0. The trigger you wrote is just changing that record.

Comment: I don't think triggers can  `UPDATE` the table they are set to trigger on, unless it is a `BEFORE UPDATE` which merely changes the values being updated.  What you should probably do instead is update *all** the rows in your initial update statement.

Comment: If you post your `UPDATE` statement I can show you what I mean.